# Get all records with child records OR field length > 250

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a `Comment` model which has-many `attachments`. What I want to return, is all of the comments which either have one or more attachment records, OR whose comment is longer than 250 characters.

Is there any way I can do this without writing it entirely in pure SQL? I'm struggling to build up a WHERE clause in just the rails method. It's not quite as simple as I'd hoped :(

Ideally I want this to be a scope but whatever will work is fine

Comment: While I don't have an answer to this question, I want to say that you shouldn't be afraid of SQL. It's the work horse of your app. AR is just a convenience wrapper on top of it. It's purpose is to simplify most common tasks. It is not meant to completely guard you from touching SQL.

Comment: You can use the outer join and count the attachment records in addition to the condition of the comments length>250

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'm not scared of it. I like using SQL I just tend to try avoiding it in Rails for portability but if there's no nicer way I guess I'll have to use it in this.

AlexBell, That was my original thought, but I wasn't sure how to then get the record back as an AR instance as the count column doesn't exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
Comment.includes(:attachments).where('attachments.comment_id IS NOT NULL OR LEN(comments.content) > 250')
```

Comment: Damnit! I did almost EXACTLY this, but forgot the `IS` keyword! Seems to work perfectly

Comment: Lots of answers work, but watch for performance. test my answers in irb and see sql generated

Answer (score 0):

The WHERE clause should follow the pattern o the following pseudo-code

```
WHERE Length(Comment_field) > 250
OR EXISTS (Select COMMENT_ID from attachments)
```

Answer (score 0):

Jump into the irb or rails c (console) do this from command-line to get it then plug it in.

```
 c     =  YourCommentModel.where('attachments > ?', 1)
len250 =  c = YourCommentModel.where('attachments.length> ?', 250)
```

first one gives comments of greater than 1, second gives comments > 250

Comment: Those are separate though. I'd then have to combine the results myself, as well as be running 2 queries. I'd rather just have the one query that does both